# Equivalent of reference pointer in C?

Tags: c

I made a linked list, and a function that returns the iterator. When assigning the iterator to another pointer and freeing the pointer, it does nothing since it's not a reference. How can I delete the item in the list?

Example:

```
//initialize struct list, insert 1 struct (this is only done if list is empty)
some_struct* struct_list;
struct_list = (some_struct*)malloc(sizeof(some_struct));
strncpy(struct_list->name, "foo", 4);
struct_list->name[3] = '\0';

typedef struct some_struct
{
    char name[MAXLENGTH];
    struct some_struct* next;
} some_struct;

some_struct* find_struct(char* name)
{
    char* iter;
    for (iter = struct_list; iter != NULL; iter = iter->next)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, iter->name) == 0)
            return iter;
    }
    return NULL;
}
some_struct* name;
name = find_struct("foo");  //since there's only 1 struct, name == struct_list
free(name);  //struct_list still contains 1 struct with name "foo"
```

I made sure the linked list works as it should, it does find the name but this doesn't do anything

**Edit:** For clarification, unlinking/linking does get rid of the struct. But if there's only 1 item in the struct, this doesn't work

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake, fixed code.  I am getting the struct in my program, still same problem

Comment: ok so your function should be called something else than `find_name`, it's confusing.

Comment: freeing the structure node doesn't remove it from your linked list. You have to do that manually. I suggest a routine to handle the unlink+free. But you have to know the previous element too. Impossible to do in a single-linked list when you have the current element.

Comment: Your code does free of the struct pointer, but now you have a dangling pointer in your struct_list. Maybe you are doing a use after free? Also your iter is a char* when I think it should be a `some_struct*`

Comment: I do unlink it, and link the previous struct to the next struct. In this example, let's say there's only 1 struct in the list, so no need for that. In fact it works as it should if there's more than 1 item, but not if there's a single one

Comment: @JoeDefill, what do you expect the observable result of deleting the last item from your list to be?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I expect the linked list to be null, but it isn't even if I explicitly assign null to the struct and free it

Comment: C does not support references!

Comment: Show **all** the relevant code, including unlinking.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - You can work round that by copying the next element into the current element, and then deleting the next element instead.  (Doesn't work if you have other pointers to the next element, obviously...)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth nice, but doesn't work if this is the last element of the list either!

Comment: I updated the code showing how I initialize and insert the first and only struct. Maybe I should be using a head pointer? I would think freeing the list works as well

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - True! Though I suppose if your list has an explicit dummy tail node, or is circularly-linked (like GCC's `std::list` implementation) then you'd be ok.

Comment: Aside: Since value of `MAXLENGTH` is not shown, `strncpy(struct_list->name, "foo", 4);
struct_list->name[3] = '\0';` --> `strncpy(struct_list->name, "foo", MAXLENGTH);
struct_list->name[MAXLENGTH-1] = '\0';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I made a linked list, and a function that returns the iterator. When assigning the iterator to another pointer and freeing the pointer, it does nothing since it's not a reference. How can I delete the item in the list?

Whether it is a reference has nothing to do with anything.  You can indeed free the memory of the list node via *any* pointer to it, but I have no idea why you think that would automatically remove it from the list, even if it were a reference.  Instead, the node's predecessor ends up with an invalid `next` pointer, and dereferencing that produces undefined behavior.  That UB could plausibly take a form similar to the behavior it would have exhibited prior to the memory being freed, at least for a time.

You seem to have it backward.  If you want to remove a node from the list then that is your *primary* objective; freeing the node's memory is secondary, and then only appropriate if you are in fact finished with the node.  Deleting from a singly-linked list requires finding the predecessor of the node to delete, then updating its `next` pointer appropriately.  Depending on exactly how you set things up, deleting the first element may be a special case.

### Update

You having clarified in comments that the issue is with deleting the only element from a one-element list (or, I'd wager, the first element no matter how long the list is), it seems appropriate to expand on the special case that I referred to.

Evidently you have a global variable

```
some_struct *struct_list;
```

that points to the first list node when there is one, and which is null when the list is empty.  Given a pointer to a node you want to delete, such as one returned by your `find_struc()` function, to delete that from your list you'll need a function along these lines:

```
void delete_struct(some_struct *to_delete) {
    if (struct_list == to_delete) {
        // special case: deleting the first element
        // ... do something here ...
    } else {
        some_struct *pred = struct_list;
        while (pred && pred->next != to_delete) {
            pred = pred->next;
        }
        if (pred) {
            assert(pred->next == to_delete);
            pred->next = pred->next->next;
            free(to_delete);
        }
    }
}
```

Evidently, then, the problem is what should be the "do something here".  But I don't see what the mystery or problem would be.  You know what's supposed to happen, and you seem capable of making it happen:

```
struct_list = struct_list->next;
free(to_delete);
```

Obviously (or maybe not so much), the variable you have to set NULL is the one that the rest of your code looks to for the list head.

If you want to remove the special-caseness of deleting the first element, then consider using a dummy head node, which need not even be dynamically allocated.  Then the first data-bearing element has a genuine (but non-data-bearing) predecessor, and you don't need a special case.  There is at least one other alternative, but you're having enough trouble with pointers already that I'll leave that one for some other time.

Comment: The problem is the "do something here" part. I've already done exactly like you said, and explicitly made the pointer to struct_list NULL and freed it. If I do it on the list itself it works fine, but if I do it on a pointer to the list then it doesn't get freed. P.S I didn't downvote

Comment: @JoeDefill, if you set `struct_list` to NULL then it is NULL until you set it to something else.  If you set some other pointer to NULL then `struct_list` is unaffected.  You seem to understand this, so I don't see what the problem is.  FWIW, you do have the alternative of passing around a pointer to your `struct_list` pointer, by which `struct_list` could be modified.  Since `struct_list` itself is in scope, however, I don't see why you would need to do that.

Comment: NMDV, yet OP's `find_struct(char* name)` is based on the `name` and not the `some_struct` so I'd expect `delete_name(char *to_delete)` - which is just a bit more complicated.  Code would not find the `struct` by name and then call `delete_struct()` as that would be 2 passes of the list.  Otherwise a very well presented answer.